# no BODY tag was found in page While Using Html component in Lwuit J2ME

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I'm using ad network in my (Lwuit) J2ME Application, but I'm having some problems, I tried to put the HTTP call of the ad in an html component but I got `No body tag was found`.

So I tried to get the response as string from the HTTP call then put it in the html component but it takes long time to open the screen which contains the ad and I have to handle the on click event.

How can I integrate my ad network in J2ME application, or is there any other component which can hold the ad?

```
    HttpRequestHandler handler=new HttpRequestHandler();
    HTMLComponent htmlC = new HTMLComponent(handler);
    htmlC.setPage("http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd?apid=357&auid=testingauid&uip=66.209.31.31&ua=testing&mode=test");
```

Answer (score 0):

The ad is designed to show within an existing HTML page. You need to download the ad content and set it to the html component while adding the appropriate  tags to the HTML.

Comment: Ok thank you , i'm trying to do this now, but do you know what is the best ad netowrk for J2ME application ?

Comment: vserv is pretty good, we integrate it seamlessly in codenameone

Comment: I tried it but until now i did not get any ad, can you help me with it alittle.

Comment: Not really, try contacting their support